# Google's Mobile View from Android

Tags: android

How is there always mobile view whenever I go to google page through my Android emulator. What decides that the request is coming from mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

UserAgent is what you are looking for. There seems to be multiple definition of it's around and I'm not an expert on the topic so good luck finding more info. :)